# React Website on domain root (AWS S3 + Cloudfront) with Wordpress blog on /blog route

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

We are running a **React web app** on our domain root (say *example.com*) via **AWS S3 + Cloudfront CDN**. We are also having a **GoDaddy managed Wordpress website** which we intend to use as our blog. We were able to map this Wordpress blog to a new sub-domain i.e. *blog.example.com* but we want to host it on *example.com/blog* (for SEO reasons).

I have tried adding the Wordpress url given by GoDaddy (say *wordpress-blog.com*) as an **Origin** in Cloudfront and added a **Behaviour** to serve the route */blog* from our domain (i.e. *example.com/blog*) with the content from this origin (i.e. *wordpress-blog.com*). After adding this, Cloudfront redirects the traffic to Worldpress url but our domain is not retained in the browser, i.e. *example.com/blog* is changed to *wordpress-blog.com/blog*

I have tried few suggestions mentioned online (without changing our S3 + Cloudfront deployment too much) but with no luck yet. Moving the Wordpress website to **AWS Lightsail** and using that as the Origin for */blog* route seems to be a possible solution but not sure if that will work.

Any suggestions on how we can keep the current web app hosted on AWS S3 + Cloudfront but still serve the */blog* route traffic from our GoDaddy managed Wordpress website without changing the domain in the browser?

Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.